# Regex php que extraiga listado de parametros de una sentencia SQL

Tags: php, sql, regex

me pudieran a ayudar con un regex en php que permita extraer todas las columnas usadas en una expresion SQL, por ejemplo, tengo la sentencia:

```
SELECT ID, NOMBRE, APELLIDO FROM usuario;
```

necesito un script que me liste en un array las columnas "ID", "NOMBRE" y "APELLIDO", teniendo en cuenta que es para sentencias mas complejas con inner joins, where, group by etc etc.

Gracias por su amable colaboración.

Comment: Hola buenas,  en el sitio no se responde a preguntas en las que no se evidencie algo que hayas intentado,  en este caso no veo que hayas intentado ninguna regex,  y tampoco que hayas consultado informacion al respecto,  porfavor añade esta informacion para nosotros poder ayudarte

Comment: @Riven, no ps muchas gracias

Comment: El funcionamiento del sitio no es nada parecido a yahoo, nosotros resolvemos dudas concretas de codigo o posibles errores obtenidos y no cosas que se pueden investigar en google, y pues... espero no sonar grosero al decirlo asi, pero es por esto que esta pregunta no es valida aqui en la comunidad, para que puedas realizar mejores preguntas a futuro te invito a leer [ask], y ya que eres nuevo en el sitio es bueno pasar por el [tour].

Answer (score 2):

Definiciones que debes tener en cuenta para trabajar con sintaxis de tipo **RegEx**.

###### Metacaracteres

Los metacaracteres especifican los caracteres que los usuarios pueden ingresar en las posiciones correspondientes.

| Carácter | Descriptión |
| --- | --- |
| `.` | Cualquier carácter. |
| `[aeiou]` | Cualquier carácter del conjunto de caracteres especificado. |
| `[^aeiou]` | Cualquier carácter individual que no pertenezca al conjunto de caracteres especificado. |
| `[0-9a-fA-F]` | Cualquier carácter individual del rango de caracteres especificado. |
| `\w` | Cualquier carácter alfanumérico. Lo mismo que .`[a-zA-Z_0-9]` |
| `\W` | Cualquier carácter no alfanumérico. Lo mismo que `[^a-zA-Z_0-9]` |
| `\d` | Cualquier carácter numérico. Lo mismo que `[0-9]` |
| `\D` | Cualquier carácter no numérico. Lo mismo que `[^0-9]` |

###### Cuantificadores

Los cuantificadores siguen un metacarácter y especifican cuántas veces se debe repetir el carácter.

| Cuantificador | Descripción | Ejemplos |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `*` | Cero o más coincidencias. Lo mismo que `{0,}` | `[a-zA-Z]`, `\w` |
| `+` | Uno o más partidos. Lo mismo que `{1,}` | `[a-zA-Z]+`, `\w+` |
| `?` | Cero o uno coincide. Lo mismo que `{0,1}` | `[a-zA-Z]?`, `\w?` |
| `{n}` | Exactamente n coincidencias. | `[0-9]{2}` |
| `{n,}` | Al menos n coincidencias. | `[0-9]{2,}` |
| `{n,m}` | Al menos n , pero no más de m coincidencias. | `[0-9]{2,7}` |

---

Soluciones que pueden ayudarte.

###### 1. Extraiga los nombres de las columnas de una sentencia SQL con Regex

Expresión regular

```
/(\w*\.*\w+|`\w*.*\w`|(\[)\w*.*(\]))+(,|\s+,|\s+FROM|\s+from)/g
```

Sentencia SQL de prueba

```
-------------------------------------------------------
SELECT  
    [a].[column_1],  
    `b`.`column_2`,  
    c.column_3,  
    col4 as column_4,  
    col5 as `column_5`,   
    col6 as [column_6],
    column_7,
    a.col8 column_8,    
    (select max(column_x) from table_d where column_y in ('1','2','3')) as column_9    
from table_a a
inner join table_b b on ...
inner join table_c c on ...
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Código generado para PHP

```
<?php
$re = '/(\w*\.*\w+|`\w*.*\w`|(\[)\w*.*(\]))+(,|\s+,|\s+FROM|\s+from)/';
$str = 'SELECT  
    [a].[column_1],  
    `b`.`column_2`,  
    c.column_3,  
    col4 as column_4,  
    col5 as `column_5`,   
    col6 as [column_6],
    column_7,
    a.col8 column_8,    
    (select max(column_x) from table_d where column_y in (\'1\',\'2\',\'3\')) as column_9    
from table_a a
inner join table_b b on ...
inner join table_c c on ...
';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print result
foreach ($matches as $valor){
    echo $valor[1] . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Salida

```
[a].[column_1]
`b`.`column_2`
c.column_3
column_4
`column_5`
[column_6]
column_7
column_8
column_9
```

###### 2. Extraiga los nombres de las tablas de una sentencia SQL con Regex

Regular expression

```
/(from|join|into)\s+([`]*\w*.*\w[`]|(\[)*\w*.*(\])|\w*\.*\w*)/g
```

Sentencia SQL de prueba

```
-------------------------------------------------------
select * into [dbo].[table_temp] 
from [dbo].[table_a] a inner join dbo.table_b b ...
join table_c c on ...
from dbo.table_d d ...
from `dbo`.`table_e` e ...
from table_f f ...
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Código generado para PHP

```
<?php
    $re = '/(from|join|into)\s+([`]*\w*.*\w[`]|(\[)*\w*.*(\])|\w*\.*\w*)/m';
    $str = 'select * into [dbo].[table_temp] 
    from [dbo].[table_a] a inner join dbo.table_b b ...
    join table_c c on ...
    from dbo.table_d d ...
    from `dbo`.`table_e` e ...
    from table_f f ...';

    preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

    // Print result
    foreach ($matches as $valor){
        echo $valor[2] . "<br>";
    }
?>
```

Salida

```
[dbo].[table_temp]
[dbo].[table_a]
dbo.table_b
table_c
dbo.table_d
`dbo`.`table_e`
table_f
```

###### Referencias

[Extraiga los nombres de las tablas de una declaración SQL con Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68889908/16731336)
[Lenguaje de expresión regular: referencia rápida](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference)
[Expresiones regulares simplificadas](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/1499/controls-and-libraries/editors-and-simple-controls/common-editor-features-and-concepts/masks/mask-type-simplified-regular-expressions)
[Prueba las expresiones regulares en línea.](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Buenas, Eduardo, bienvenido al sitio. La respuesta así a priori parece correcta, pero el idioma oficial es el español, quizás debería traducir los pequeños textos que encabezan cada apartado. Por otro lado, quizás sería interesante que explicaras un poco los distintos elementos que constituyen la expresión regular. Creo que incluso podrías ofrecer una más sencilla para lo que pedía el OP en su día y luego ampliar esa con la que has puesto.

Comment: Estuve buscando algunas ideas para mí, pero no las encontré, así que toca dejar algo. Espero que la disfruten.